# How to get All input bottom of POST in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-request, laravel-7

I have this form in *Laravel*:

```xml
<form method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <button type="submit" value="happy" id="happy" name="reaction" class="border-0 btn-submit">
        <img src="/assets/images/reactions/happy.png" />
    </button>

    <button type="submit" value="angry" id="angry" name="reaction" class="border-0 btn-submit">
        <img src="/assets/images/reactions/angry.png" />
    </button>
    <button type="submit" value="ill" id="ill" name="reaction" class="border-0 btn-submit">
        <img src="/assets/images/reactions/ill.png" />
    </button>
    <button type="submit" value="love" id="love" class="border-0 btn-submit">
        <img src="/assets/images/reactions/in-love.png" />
    </button>
    <button type="submit" value="quiet" id="quiet" class="border-0 btn-submit">
        <img src="/assets/images/reactions/quiet.png" />
    </button>
    <button type="submit" value="sad" id="sad" class="border-0 btn-submit">
        <img src="/assets/images/reactions/sad.png" />
    </button>
    <!-- <input type="text" name="studentName" id="studentName" class="form-control" placeholder="please type in your name"> -->

    <input type="hidden" value="{{$article->id}}" id="post_id">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
</form>
```

After I'm in controller get all data from post is not working:

```js
$request->request->all(); //Get all post requests


switch ($request->request->input('reaction')) {
    case 'happy':
        return response()->json(['success' => "happy"]);
        break;

    case 'angry':
        return response()->json(['success' => "angry"]);
        break;

    case 'ill':
        return response()->json(['success' => "ill"]);
        break;
}
```

I'm trying these codes one by one but it does not give me results, ot only gives me one result:

```
return $request->all(); 
$request->request->get('my_param'); 
$request->request->post('my_param'); 
$request->request->input('my_param');
```

But NO working! And I'm tired for try to get button value or input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you look for is

`$request->all()` and not `$request->request->all()`

The key of value will also be what you specify in the `name` attribute on the element, whilst `value` will be the value.

```
    <button type="submit" value="happy" id="happy" name="reaction" class="border-0 btn-submit">
        <img src="/assets/images/reactions/happy.png" />
    </button>


var_dump($request->all());

array() [
  'reaction' => 'happy'
]
```

Comment: Hi i need get this same
$request->happy(); or $request->input('reaction')
thanks

Comment: Yes, $request->all() will show "['reaction' => 'happy']" whilst $request->input('reaction') will show "happy"